# Why is bash ">" string comparison failing for path names?

Tags: string, bash, command-line, path

In these three short tests only the second one works out correctly:

```
$ if [[ "/etc/cupshelpers" > "/etc/cups/interfaces" ]]; then echo ">"; else echo "<="; fi
<=
$ if [[ "/etc/cupsh" > "/etc/cups/" ]]; then echo ">"; else echo "<="; fi
>
$ if [[ "/etc/cupshe" > "/etc/cups/i" ]]; then echo ">"; else echo "<="; fi
<=
```

The issue became apparent when I sorted a list of directories and the results were different from `tree` command:

```
$ tree /etc/cups* -d
/etc/cups
├── interfaces
├── ppd
└── ssl [error opening dir]
/etc/cupshelpers
```

Any clues?

Thanks.

---

**Edit** - Reply to comments in accepted answer:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ uname -a
Linux dell 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

**Edit** Proving it works (You can try on your own non-Mac machine).

```
$ if [[ "/etc/cupshelpers" > "/etc/cups/interfaces" ]]; then echo ">"; else echo "<="; fi
<=
$ LANG=C
$ if [[ "/etc/cupshelpers" > "/etc/cups/interfaces" ]]; then echo ">"; else echo "<="; fi
>
```

---

**Edit** New problem is "X" comes before "a".

```
$  if [[ "/etc/X11/xsm" > "/etc/acpi" ]]; then echo ">"; else echo "<="; fi
>
$ echo $LANG
en_CA.UTF-8
$ LANG=C
$ if [[ "/etc/X11/xsm" > "/etc/acpi" ]]; then echo ">"; else echo "<="; fi
<=
```

There is nothing extraordinary I'm trying to accomplish. I generate a list of directory names (3,000 to 20,000) using the `tree` command. Later I append a directory to the list and I need to resort the internal bash array. During the bash bubble sort the collating sequence results on hundreds of extra directories moving up the list out of sequence.

I don't think I need a special collating sequence, just what the `tree` or `ls` commands use.

Comment: Have you tried setting `LANG=C` in your environment before running the tests?  (Keep track of what it is before you set it so you can reset it afterwards.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Aww it works. Can you post an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comment into answer.*</sup>

Have you tried setting `LANG=C` in your environment before running the tests?  (Keep track of what it is before you set it so you can reset it afterwards.)

I should note that although this seems to work for the OP in their environment, it didn't seem to make a difference for me on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 — whether using native Bash 3.2.x or a more modern Bash 4.3.x.

Your mileage may vary, therefore.

Comment: Although it fixed the problem with `/etc/cupsholder` it created a new problem: `if [[ "/etc/X11/xsm" > "/etc/acpi" ]]; then echo ">"; else echo "<="; fi` returns `<=`.  It should have returned `>` though. Resetting to default language `en_CA.UTF-8` gives the correct result. Can you recommend any links for further reading on bash sort  hierarchies?

Comment: You're going to need to find, or create, a locale such that the collation is what you want. The X11 result is what should be expected from the C collations. Things are sorted in coldest order. It sounds like you want a case-insensitive collation that doesn't ignore punctuation.  I don't know where you find one.

Comment: I've updated the question explaining why a special collation shouldn't be required because it's basic directory sorting. Do you think I need to dig into `tree` or `ls` source code to see what "locale" they use?

Comment: You may need to look at the code for `ls`, `tree` and `bash` to see what function(s) they use to sort the data into order (as well as whether they set the locale, and what they set it to).  You may find they do it 3 different ways, and reconciling the 3 isn't feasible.  You may find that 2 are consistent and one is not; you have to decide how much that matters.

Comment: I've solved this issue. The problem I was solving collating on a punctuation by punctuation basis. When in reality all I had to use was `[:alnum:]` test case on the key to match `tree` sorting style. I feel like I should post an answer on this but don't know if that's frowned upon in this community.

Comment: You may always add your own answer, and after 48 hours you can accept it.  I won't be offended by the unacceptance of my answer — indeed, I'll probably delete it.

Comment: I'd rather give you the points :) Besides I'm working on another self-answered Question related to your post on using associated arrays to link tp indexed array which will become hugely popular with 1 possible 2 upvotes ;) In all seriousness your answer was correct at the time and I just wanted to post an answer for others who might be going down the same path (pun intended). I think the appropriate step is to just revise the question with a final edit.

Comment: Up to you — that also works.  If you do edit the question, I suggest removing today's comments — you can flag mine obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on flagging comments obsolete. I never heard of that in Ask Ubuntu (where I hail from) and always keep pinging via comment "I'll delete mine if you delete yours". It won't be for a few days, I'm busy bench marking bash array bubble sorting vs. using linux sort on key-subscript pair work file.